# Displaying Font Colors in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, fonts, matlab-uitable

I am trying to create an array of numbers (converted to string) that fall bellow a thresh hold, for my current testing i'm using 0.5.  I need the font of every value of my table that falls above or below my thresh hold to be colored red, in my current code i'm only using 2 columns, but I will be using more than 10.  This is my code right now and it is only displaying the numbers values above 0.5 in color red but it's not displaying the numbers below 0.5 (they should be in black). 
I'm sorry for the bad naming of the variables, I'm just testing to implement this. Help will be greatly appreciated.

```
TTT = rand(30,2);
for u = 1:2

PPP = TTT(1:30, u:u);

   RRR = ( PPP(:) > .5);

   AAA = reshape(strtrim(cellstr(num2str(TTT(:)))), size(TTT));

   QQQQ(RRR, u) = strcat(...
   '<html><span style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;">', ...
    AAA(RRR, u), ...
   '</span></html>');


end
%# create table
f = figure;
h = uitable('Parent',f, 'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0.05 0.05 0.9 0.9]);

%# set table data
set(h, 'Data',QQQQ)
```

Comment: It would be best if you could post a complete code example that we can copy and paste to try it out. In your code, `TTT` is not defined.

Comment: TTT is a random array generated by matlab, (30 x 2). I may have made a mistake copy pasting the variable PPP but everything is working. Edited the the code now.

Comment: +1 for directly-runnable code

Comment: I must have missed that first line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not filling all values in `QQQQ`, only those which will be in red. The rest (which should be in black) are left as empty cells, and thus they are not shown.

To correct this, You need to initialize `QQQQ` to `AAA`, and *then* modify color for the relevant cells. So, add

```
AAA = reshape(strtrim(cellstr(num2str(TTT(:)))), size(TTT));
QQQQ = AAA;
```

right before the `for` loop, and remove the `AAA = reshape...` line from within the loop. That is:

```
TTT = rand(30,2);
AAA = reshape(strtrim(cellstr(num2str(TTT(:)))), size(TTT));
QQQQ = AAA;
for u = 1:2
   PPP = TTT(1:30, u:u);
   RRR = ( PPP(:) > .5);
   QQQQ(RRR, u) = strcat(...
      '<html><span style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;">', ...
      AAA(RRR, u), ...
      '</span></html>');
end

%# create table
f = figure;
h = uitable('Parent',f, 'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0.05 0.05 0.9 0.9]);

%# set table data
set(h, 'Data',QQQQ)
```

Comment: Thanks allot!!! that really solved the first half of my problems, I also need the fonts of all values in column 1 to also be colored red if they are above 0.50.

Comment: @Stephan Sorry. The initiallizaton has to be done before the `for` loop. See updated answer

Comment: Wow, thanks allot Luis it worked perfectly. I never notice those errors,  thanks again, I spent allot of hours figuring this out.

Comment: @Stephan Glad I could help. As you probably know, you should consider upvoting and/or marking the answer as accepted if it solved your problem :-)

Comment: This QA taught me something new (handling html in table data), I'll handle the upvote that Stephan can't.  ;)